# Wordpress custom post types and MANY images

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I will be using Wordpress as a CMS with custom post types.  Each "post" is a product and will have 20-60 images in 3 different sizes (60-180 total images per product).

**What's the best way to link the images to the post?**

I'm thinking about storing them on Amazon S3 and recording the URLs in custom meta tags, but I want to make sure I do it in a way that its easy to retrieve.

Comment: Here is a plugin can do the job http://wordpress.org/plugins/multi-image-upload/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The WordPress has a built-in media library which has hooks that relate images to specific posts (products in your case). Given that [a solid API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference#Attachments) exists for this, you may want to start there.

Helpful functions to look into are:

1. [`wp_insert_attachment`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_attachment)
2. [`wp_delete_attachment`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_delete_attachment)
3. [`wp_get_attachment_image_src`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image_src)
4. [`wp_get_attachment_metadata`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_metadata)

**Update**: To be more specific for this project, also be sure to look into [`add_image_size`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_image_size) which allows you to define various thumbnail sizes which your posts can use. In other words, upload one large image and WP will automatically generate the rest. Mark J. of the WP team made a good [writeup](http://markjaquith.wordpress.com/2009/12/23/new-in-wordpress-2-9-post-thumbnail-images/) of the feature back wen 2.9 was released.

As for the S3, that definitely isn't a bad idea either, but keep WP as being your core source of data. Perhaps you can use a back-end process to move them to S3 and then update the attachment's metadata. When you render the post, check to see if a S3 URI exists, otherwise default to a local image.

(Disclosure: I'm not very familiar w/S3; but this is how I would start my quest.)

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Is Wordpress able to handle the high volume of photos that I would need to import?  There will be thousands.  I think keeping them outside of Wordpress and using URLs to reference may help with performance.

Comment: Certainly. With regards to performance, I find that most optimizations should be performed at the DB and/or system level.